# Is there a way to use action.yml with container repository's GitHub action

Tags: docker, github, containers, token, github-actions

I want to create a github action that will be used as a github action from container repository like described here:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-a-docker-public-registry-action

Is there a way to have action.yml describing this container?
Is no, is there a way to forward an input with default value from "expression" for getting the GitHub token like here on regular action.yml:

```yaml
...
inputs:
  ...
  token:
    description: 'GitHub Temporary Token'
    required: false
    default: ${{ github.token }}
  ...
...
```

Couldn't find a documentation on internet.

Answer (score 0):

You would pass in the input pretty much as you've defined it.  However, I would advise you make the token required and remove the default setting.

Instead, have the workflow that calls your action pass in the token from there:

Your action:

```
...
inputs:
  ...
  token:
    description: 'GitHub Temporary Token'
    required: true
  ...
...
```

The workflow:

```
    ...
    steps:
      - uses: your-username/your-action@v1
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    ...
```

Also, check here for documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions

Specifically here:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#runs-for-docker-actions

So you would call a public image like this:

```
runs:
  using: 'docker'
  image: public-image@tag
```